# Error inflating com.google.ads.AdView

Tags: android, admob, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I am trying to integrate google ads to my game. But when I run this code, I got an exception. Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/podklad">
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7921725136909046/2004996412"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

I deleted some button definitions because they are not important

and this is my logcat:

```
Process: com.tproductions.monstertap, PID: 5846
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tproductions.monstertap/com.tproductions.monstertap.MainMenuActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51:       Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:297)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
        at com.tproductions.monstertap.MainMenuActivity.onCreate(MainMenuActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you using "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" as your namespace for the ads attributes?  The package names for it and the tag do not correspond.

Try "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" (see https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start#step_1_create_fragment_adxml)